# What does "Yer makin’ my neck itchy.” mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> No need ta be so formal. Yer makin’ my neck itchy. Talk normal, got it? ([Source](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/12469253/4/Is-it-wrong-to-be-a-Hero-in-a-dungeon))

I have no idea what does "Yer makin’ my neck itchy."  mean. I guess the phrase has some figurative meaning.

Comment: ta = to; Yer = you are; makin' = making.   You are causing me to feel some discomfort (itchiness).  The spelling is an attempt to present the speaker's pronunciation. "talk normal" is substandard for "speak normally".

Comment: Yeah. That said, I don't know why hearing "formal" talk would make one's neck itch.

Answer (score 2):

Possible reason: Until about 100 years ago, well-dressed men wore starched collars, at least in formal situations. These were very stiff and scratchy. Even now, when I'm wearing a tie with my ordinary modern business shirt, my neck gets itchy. (I don't usually wear a tie.)

Comment: +1 A starched collar was the first thing that came to mind when I read it. A related phrase is "starched shirt" - for example, from an [editorial review of a Mark Twain book](https://www.amazon.com/Tramp-Abroad-Mark-Twain-ebook/dp/B0084B00G6): "Sidestepping the **starched-shirt diction** of his peers, he created an idiom that resembled (but did not precisely duplicate) the wayward, slangy, ungrammatical music of American conversation."

Answer (score 0):

I think it simply means, "You're making me feel uncomfortable."

It's not an established idiom, though; I'd guess it's a creative expression coined by the author. I could only find two instances of it on the Internet (the original story, and this ELL question). Moreover, when I tried to use a more formal form ("you're making my neck itchy"), Google said:

> No results found for "you're making my neck itchy".

Answer (score 0):

He's just saying it very informally, but what he's trying to convey is that he feels uncomfortable because the person whom he is speaking to is speaking formally.